# Objective C: Passing variables between classes

Tags: objective-c, timer, messaging

I want to pass an NSMutableDictionary from one class through a timer to another class that is called from the timer. I get an error at `@selector([generateStickFig:enemies])` I've tried taking [] out but it still errs.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {

//start timer that fires every second
NSMutableDictionary *enemies = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.001) target:self selector:@selector([generateStickFig:enemies]) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void) generateStickFig:(NSMutableDictionary *)enemies {

int x = random() % 1000;

if (x == 1) {
    stickFig = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 650, 50, 50)];
    [stickFig setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [stickFig addTarget:self action:@selector(tapFig:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [enemies setObject:object forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"object%i",i]];
    [self.view addSubview:stickFig];
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.001) target:self selector:@selector(generateStickFig:) userInfo:enemies repeats:YES];
```

to create the timer. Then change the callback method to

```
-(void) generateStickFig:(NSTimer *)timer {
NSDictionary *enemies = (NSDictionary *)timer.userInfo;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this works, it compiles now. One question though, how does it know which variable to send over if you're not including it in the selector

Comment: If you have multiple variables to send over, you should pack them into a dictionary and pass the dictionary into the userInfo: argument.

Comment: You include the enemies dictionary as the userInfo parameter. I forgot, that you have to change the callback method a little, though. I edited the necessary changes into my answer.